# How to prevent ISP from sniffing HTTPS traffic and tampering it

Tags: https, privacy, isp

India's telecom provider is intercepting including HTTPS and tampering it with custom page.

Sample:

```
curl -H "Host: thepiratebay.org" http://192.30.253.112/
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0"/><style>body{margin:0px;padding:0px;}iframe{width:100%;height:100%}</style><iframe src="http://www.airtel.in/dot/?dpid=1&dpruleid=3&cat=107&ttl=0&groupname=-&policyname=-&username=-&userip=122.171.125.65&connectionip=127.0.0.1&nsphostname=Policy04-Chennai&protocol=policyprocessor&dplanguage=-&url=http%3a%2f%2fthepiratebay%2eorg%2f" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0></iframe>
```

Description about this https tampering is here: https://medium.com/@karthikb351/airtel-is-sniffing-and-censoring-cloudflares-traffic-in-india-and-they-don-t-even-know-it-90935f7f6d98

So is there any way to avoid it from end user side?

Comment: Your best bet would be using a VPN service and proxy your traffic from an outside server

Comment: Though it'll work, it's not always feasible solution.

Comment: @ Jones - I've yet to see a VPN which is not feasible if you control the endpoints. VPNs can be configured to run over pretty much any available protocol, including http, https and DNS.

Comment: @davidgo Couple of banking website place temporary/permanent ban while logging from VPN. Additionally I prefer some fix than a service if possible

Comment: You can't control other people's networks or routers with "fixes" on your devices. You are also confusing VPN as a class of solution (which no provider can block for web traffic while still allowing the greater public), and VPN offerings by known providers with known endpoints. Nothing to stop you spinning up your own VPN on a virtual server you buy.

Answer (score -1):

You can't control how traffic travels through a network with some kind of "fix" on your computer, see, the only way you can avoid your ISP's network is by using a VPN (though you will still have to use it for a brief moment until it exits their network) and you also get a path, probably encrypted, where data will flow back. Once it's outside they won't have a way of knowing who started the communication from the inside without having direct access to the VPN's logs. But since you said it's not always feasible (because of some sites restricting traffic from them) then there's no way you can access them without using your ISP's network, your best bet would be using HTTPS (even if they can't know what data goes through them, they will still know who and where did it go, and companies could probably just offer them the rest of the information anyway), but aside from that, there are no other options. Happy browsing.

Comment: Nobody is trying to change any fact, I'm just saying that you maybe have to check your attitude when making certain statements and choose your words wisely beforehand.

Comment: I was extremely polite in my original comment.  I even repeated and clarified my original suggestion.  I very respectfully suggested you edit your answer because it appeared in the [low quality review queue](https://superuser.com/review/low-quality-posts/693714) If I have shown you any disrespect then that wasn’t my attention.  I hope you will take the time to improve your answer.  Wish you luck and good times, going to enjoy this wonderful day, and avoid this further discussion of this toooc.

Comment: I upvoted this, although it's incorrect on the point there are no other options. You could use a proxy or cache to route traffic in place of a VPN

Comment: @davidgo you're right, although I think the use of a VPN implies proxying the traffic, though I wasn't explicit.